# Translation of 習慣養成實作指南！

Tags: translation

I was working on translating the Amazon page for Atomic Habits and I ran into this sentence:

一出版立刻風行全球，企業界、運動界、教育界、瘦身界都在用的習慣養成實作指南！

Does this seem like a correct translation?

As soon as it was published, it became popular worldwide. The business, exercise, education, and weight-loss industries all use this practical habit formation guide.

Does 實作指南 mean practical guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the translation and you are correct. Note the full title of the guide is "習慣養成實作指南".

Note: The original book title is "Tiny Changes, Remarkable Results - Automic Habits." (An Amazon eBook). I think it could be translated more close to the original, such as "小改變大成果 - 好習慣養成實作指南".